# Move Azure subscription to another tenant with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

We have to move many subscriptions to another tenant. 
How can this be automated with Powershell?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This isn't google... Please try to do some research yourself. If you come up with a possible solution and need help on certain problems we will gladly help you. Also please take a look at [ask], tour and [mcve].

Comment: Hi, sorry if I missed something - its my first question. Already googled for a long time without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isnt possible with powershell, you can only do this by contacting support.

Comment: But you can do it from the portal yourself :) Probably not with PowerShell though.

Comment: I was afraid it´s not possible. @ juunas:Manually it works - on subscription level with button "Switch directory" and choose the target directory. Prerequisite is creating the accounts in the target tenant before.